# How to call new instance or reload the MainPage when click button to navigate from second page to main page - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I have a problem with xamarin.forms.maps when I switch from second page to the main page (my map is zoom outed and I cant find where is my pins). So is there a way to call again MainPage like a new instance or reload the constructor in the MainPage ?

This is main page when app start:

[image: When app start]

This is when I switched from second page to main page:

[image: When switch from second page to main page]

So I try with navigation and without navigation, but the result is the same..

How to call a new instance when I clicked on the button from the second page to call MainPage ?

This is my App.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

This is the back button from second page to main page:

```
private void OnButtonClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
        //await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
```

I want when I switch to the main page to reload again ?

**UPDATE**

Maybe now I call the main page with new instance, but my map is not calling all parts.. can I call the main page without new instance ...

Comment: you are already creating a new instance of MainPage every time, which is not a good idea.  You should navigate back to the existing instance.

Comment: Can you give me some example ?

Comment: if you are using `NavigationPage` just call `PopAsync` to return to the previous page

Comment: When I use PopAsync in my second page just like that:  await Navigation.PopAsync();

When I start app, the map is out zoomed..

Comment: if you Pop back to a page it should be in the same state it was in before, unless you are doing something to change it

Comment: I fix the bug, when I use IsZooomEnabled = true; with PopAsync(), Thank you !